# How to prove the Tauber's second theorem?

Tags: calculus

The Tauber's second theorem states as follows :
$$\sum c_n=s\Leftrightarrow c_n \; is \; Abel \; Summable \; and \; \sum_1^n kc_k=o(n)$$
I search it in all of my textbooks , and the Wikipedia , but no results  , wait your   nice answer !

Answer (score 0):

I think I got one .
$\Rightarrow$ The Abel summable comes from the Abel Lemma, to the second part, we use the summation by part $$\sum kc_k=-\sum s_n+ns_n$$
The $s_n$ denotes the n-th partial sums of $c_n$,and it converges , then we can use the Stolz Law to compute the limit.

$\Leftarrow$ 
$$|\sum_1^\infty r^nc_n-\sum_1^Nc_n|\leq (1-r)|\sum_1^Nnc_n|+R_N$$
Here $R_N$ is the remainder of that Abel Means , and let $$r=1-1/N$$
letting N tends to infinity , that ends the proof.